# Yet another word riddle

Tags: riddle, word, acrostic

> Getting rid of me would be paradoxical, but if you did it, you would be enlightened.
>
> If you called a doctor, I would become inactive.
>
> If you are lost, just try to think of me.
>
> If you want to know what I am, you first need to solve me.

What am I?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> A riddle

If you called a doctor, I would become inactive

> RIDDLE - DR = IDLE. Other clues just seem to indicate self-referentiality.

Comment: If this is the intended solution shouldn't the 2 letters rot13(q , e) be together?

Comment: Yes! That was the solution but you did nothing on the first line!

Comment: @DrD I didn't pretend it to be on that specific order, just to remove those rot13(q , e) and playing with the remaining.